# Uploading file to S3 using a pre-signed URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, upload, xmlhttprequest, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload a file in my s3 bucket with an AWS pre-signed URL.

Here is my JS function:

```js
function UploadObjectUsingPresignedURL() {
    var file = document.getElementById('customFile').files[0];
    console.log(file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('PUT', 'hereMyPresignedURL', true);
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log('Uploaded data successfully');
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = () => {
      console.log('Nope')
    };
    xhr.send(file); // `file` is a File object here 
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile"
            aria-describedby="customFile">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="customFile" 
        onclick="UploadObjectUsingPresignedURL()">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here the result in my console...

[image: console output]

> functions.js:4 File {name: "aragorn.jpg", lastModified: 1590136296908, lastModifiedDate: Fri May 22 2020 10:31:36 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 7714, …}
> functions.js:10 Uploaded data successfully)

So it seems it went well (Uploaded data successfully), but in my S3 bucket I have no new files... since I have no error, I don't know how to debug this.

Here is my .NET code for generating the pre-signed URL:

```cs
public static string MakeS3PresignedURIUpload() {
    string awsAccessKeyId = "XXX";
    string awsSecretAccessKey = "XXX";
    string s3Bucket = "test-bucket";
    string s3Key = "/aragorn.jpg";
    string awsRegion = "us-west-2";


    string presignedUri = "Error : No S3 URI found!";
    int expirationMinutes = 60;

    if (s3Bucket != String.Empty && s3Key != String.Empty && awsRegion != String.Empty) {
        try {
            s3Key = s3Key.Replace("\\", "/");
            GetPreSignedUrlRequest presignedUriReq = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
            RegionEndpoint myRegion = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(awsRegion);
            AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, myRegion);
            presignedUriReq.Verb = HttpVerb.PUT;
            presignedUriReq.BucketName = s3Bucket;
            presignedUriReq.Key = s3Key;
            presignedUriReq.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expirationMinutes);
            presignedUri = client.GetPreSignedURL(presignedUriReq); }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e) {
            return string.Format("Error : S3 - MakeS3PresignedURIUpload - Error encountered on server.Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return string.Format("Error : S3 - MakeS3PresignedURIUpload - Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
        }
    }
    return presignedUri;
}
```

Comment: maybe also console.log(xhr.responseText) to find out more about the response from aws? Are you using the AWS S3 console to view the files?

Comment: @wschopohl Thanks for your comment :) Yes I use https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/ to view the files. I just try console.log(xhr.responseText) and console.log(xhr.response) and both are empty ... What does that mean ?

Comment: Hmm, I think it should mean it worked, like you said.. How are you generating the presignedUrl? I think you need to set a 'Content-Type' Request Header in your presignedUrl code and in you xml request..

Comment: @wschopohl I added in the post the function for generate the presigned-URL. It's just for test so I just run this .NET project in the console, and I copy/paste the returned URL in my JS project. But if I add a Content-Type, I can only send the same type of file ? If I want to send a jpg file and then a pdf file ?

Comment: From what I read it is important to set ContentType in your .NET code and in your js code, maybe give it a try! Apart from that I think you need a new presigned url for any new file put request anyway ..

Comment: How did you even get that far? anytime i try a put to the bucket from the clients browser to the s3 bucket using a presigned url i get a preflight "OPTIONS" request which fails as aws does not allow "OPTIONS" as an allowed method in there cors.
It then does not even botter doing the put command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s3Key = "/aragorn.jpg";
```

Change to

```
string s3Key = "aragorn.jpg";
```

It was working, but saving the file in an un-named folder in the bucket and not directly in the bucket ...