# Is there a way to make an upload to AWS bucket from the web

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I have a website and I want to have an upload button that will, instead of uploading to a certain directory on my webroot, upload to an AWS bucket. How can I do this? Will I need a server-side scripting language?

Thanks

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is a website where people volunteer their free time to help random strangers. It is not a service people are paid for, which is why it's usually constructive to phrase questions in a way that make helping you easy and then being patient. Comments that I perceive as passive aggressive don't necessarily make me want to spend my time trying to figure out what you're trying to do. Here are two pointers [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321991/) + [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: [Uploading objects using presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of this use case. In this AWS tutorial, a Spring boot application is used that lets a user upload images to an Amazon S3 bucket.

[image]

So this is possible with a web application. For details, see this URL:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app